# Which cell balancing method (active or passive) is best for low-voltage BMS (Battery Management System)?

Tags: automotive, cell-balancing

As a beginner, I am going to design and develop a BMS (Battery Management System) for low-voltage applications (electric bike). So I would like to know which cell balancing method is perfect for low-voltage BMS.

**Is active cell balancing method (fixed resistor, shunt resistor) or passive cell balancing methods best for low-voltage battery pack?**

How should I decide that?

Please explain in a way that will be helpful as a beginner.

Comment: you should describe both methods a little more so that anyone answering has a better understanding of what your knowledge is. Nobody is going to answer from the bottom up starting at ohms law so, do yourself a favour and allow people into your current knowledge levels.

Comment: first of all Thank you so much Andy for the comment . After seeing your comment i realized asking question without researching in deep is wrong so now i have researched in Deep and i came up between two methods. i will put that as seperate question thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general remark: There is no such thing as a perfect system. Every technical system comes with a set of complex tradeoffs and one needs to decide which parameter to favour.

There is not just one method of active balancing. Every active balancing system will come with its own set of complexities and benefits. I personally only looked into the tradeoff between charging efficiency and system complexity.

When I last looked into this tradeoff (3 years ago) i kind of discovered that active balancing was a bit overhyped. In most cases you will not really see a large enough difference in charging efficiency to merit the increase in system complexity.

Every published work that tried to show (or sell?) active balancing is a good idea first placed the cells into an extremely unbalanced state (>10% state of charge difference). And even with this massively unbalanced stack they really did not show huge improvements to the charging efficiency compared to the much simpler passive balancing option.

My own personal experiments showed that batteries really do not get out of balance to that degree unless you have a general system problem. In which case balancing is not the way to go but you really need to fix the problem itself. (If you try to fix it with balancing then you will still have to deal with the problem of different ageing speeds that may result from such a systematic problem)